# Webpack plugin watching child compilation

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

The plugin [compiles an additional asset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987626/using-a-loader-inside-a-webpack-plugin/30344170#30344170) during the `emit` phase:

```
MyPlugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
  compiler.plugin('emit', function(compilation, callback) {
    var outputOptions = {
      filename: 'output.js',
      publicPath: compilation.outputOptions.publicPath
    };
    var childCompiler = compilation.createChildCompiler('MyPluginCompilation', outputOptions);
    childCompiler.apply(new NodeTemplatePlugin(outputOptions));
    childCompiler.apply(new LibraryTemplatePlugin('result', 'var'));
    childCompiler.apply(new NodeTargetPlugin());
    childCompiler.apply(new SingleEntryPlugin(this.context, 'my-loader!input.js'));
    childCompiler.runAsChild(callback);
  });
};
```

This works very well however webpack doesn't watch the specified `'input.js'` file when using the `webpack-dev-server`.

**How do I have to set up my webpack child compilation to recompile on file change?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The watch is started at the `after-compile` step, which runs *before* `emit`, so your child compiler's file dependencies are never added to the list of files to watch.

You should use `make` instead of `emit`. It's the [recommended interface](http://webpack.github.io/docs/plugins.html#make-parallel) for adding entries and modules to your compilation.