# Can I use other plugins in my plugin in webpack 4?

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

I have a working webpack configuration.
Now I want to make a single plugin.
I tried this suggestion but no success.
[Using a loader inside a webpack plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987626/using-a-loader-inside-a-webpack-plugin)

Answer (score 3):

This was the solution for me

```
module.exports = class MyPlugin {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        this.options = options;
    }
    apply(compiler) {
        new OtherPlugin({}).apply(compiler);
    }
}
```